# Why is React setting the state to what was *previously* clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dateClicked: ''
        };
    }

    onDateClick(date) {
        this.setState({
            currentDateEntry: date
        });
        console.log(this.state.currentDateEntry);
    }

  render ....
}
```

I have a HTML list of dates. When I perform the first click, it console logs `null`. I have to click on the same date again, for it to console log the correct date. If I then click on a different date, it will console log the previous date (i.e. - it is unchanged). I have to click on that second date once more for the state to be set to the new date.

So the process is somethign like this:

(action, state of dateClicked):
(click on date x, null),
(click on date x, date x),
(click on date y, date x),
(click on date y, date y)

What is causing this? Why isn't the state updating correctly?

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) explains:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

Comment: To add on to this answer, you can pass a callback function as the second argument to `setState` and it will be invoked once the state change has been committed.

Comment: @AlanH it's also documented in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with callbacks or use the ReactJS lifecycle methods https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

E.g. componentWillUpdate:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state.currentDateEntry);
}
```